# Why Dim as New and Dim/Set in VBA behave differently when I call a COM server?

Tags: vba, com

I have made an out-of-process COM server (C++) that is called from VBA.

For an unknown reason when I call it multiple times (at least two times in the same sub) I'm only able to call it using  `Dim xx As New xxx`.

When I try to call it using  `Dim xxx As xxx` and then `Set xx = new xxx` , my com server raises a violation reading exception and VBA returns the error code `800706BE`.

The following code does work (pseudo code - I removed the irrelevant part). Note that the 'Main' sub call the 'aux' function and that both the Sub and the 'aux' function call my COM server (two different classes).

```
Function aux() As Double()

    Dim com As New COMServer.classe2

    Dim Returns() As Double
    Returns = com.Method2 'actual call to the COM Server
    aux = Returns
End Function

Sub Main()
     Dim Resultat() As Double

     Dim com1 As New COMServer.classe1

     Dim Returns() As Double
     Returns = aux ' call Function aux
     Resultat = com1.Method1(Returns)  'actual call to the COM Server
End Sub
```

The following **does not** work :

```
 Function aux() As Double()

        Dim com As COMServer.classe2
        Set com  = New COMServer.classe2

        Dim Returns() As Double
        Returns = com.Method2 'actual call to the COM Server
        aux = Returns
End Function

Sub Main()
     Dim Resultat() As Double

     Dim com1 As  COMServer.classe1
     Set com1  = New COMServer.classe1

     Dim Returns() As Double
     Returns = aux ' call Function aux
     Resultat = com1.Method1(Returns)   'a violation reading (c++) Exception is thrown here
End Sub
```

Can someone explain me why my code only works in the first case ?

Also note that if I only call the server once in the sub (no call to aux), then both methods ( Dim as New and Dim/Set ) work.

---

**EDIT**

I have noticed that in case 1 (the case that works) : my server automatically start and stop two times consecutively (seen in the Windows Task Manager ).

Whereas in second case (the buggy one) : my server start only once - didn't stop and raise the error.

Now I have just modified the second case in the following manner and the exception disappears :

```
Sub Main()
     Dim Resultat() As Double

     Dim Returns() As Double
     Returns = aux ' call Function aux

     Dim com1 As  COMServer.classe1
     Set com1  = New COMServer.classe1
     Resultat = com1.Method1(Returns)   'no more Exception 
End Sub
```

The only difference is that I set my server just before to call it (instead to initialize it before to call my 'aux" function). 
**Does it makes sense to someone** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dim` statements aren't executable. `Set` statements are.

When you do `Dim foo As New Bar` you're creating an *auto-instantiated object variable*, which incurs a bit of overhead in the VBA runtime (every call against it validates whether there's a valid object reference).

This is how auto-instantiated objects bite:

```
Dim foo As New Collection
Set foo = Nothing
foo.Add 42 'runtime error 91? nope.
Debug.Print foo.Count ' prints 1
Set foo = Nothing
Debug.Print foo.Count ' runtime error 91? nope. prints 0
```

So `As New` makes VBA go out of its way to ensure there's always a valid object reference for that pointer, no matter what. Every member call on object variables declared `As New` is valid: VBA will *create* a new instance before making the member call if the reference points to `Nothing` - that's the overhead I mentioned earlier, and contradicts [LS_dev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882439/1188513). Auto-instantiated object variables aren't "only instantiated on first member call" - they're instantiated *whenever they need to be*.

The answer is likely in your C++ code, not in the client VBA code. *Something* is wrong with how you're cleaning things up, there's loose ends *somewhere* - using `As New` to work around a sloppy COM server doesn't strike me as a good idea (`As New` should generally be avoided, as a matter of fact, for the unintuitive behavior depicted above).

Comment: thanks, see my edit please, the exception disappears after I rearranged the initialization of my server but I don't understand why.

Comment: I don't think your question is fully answerable without the C++ code. The two initializations correspond to the two `As New` declarations; why it stops is not VBA's fault, but likely a bug in the COM server.

Comment: You were right, problem came from my c++ code, I initialized some third part runtime in my ATL classes instead of inside the main `CAtlExeModuleT` module.  Now that's works for both cases, thank to point it me in to the correct direction and for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Problem may be in sequence of call. From my experience, objects declare with `As New` are only instantiated in first member call, while `Set ... = New` instantiate object immediately.

Said so, in first case `classe2` is created before `classe1` which is only created when you call `com1.Method1`.

In second case, `classe1` is created in `Set`, before `classe2`.

taking this into account, it seams your COM code somehow create a memory violation if `classe1` is created before `classe2`.

Comment: thanks for this idea, I'm investigating it but a prior the two classes should be independent.